# Read pymatgen format from something else other than Python?

Tags: pymatgen, openbabel, materials-project

It seems that the only way that Materials Project can report structures with the new API is through the Pymatgen JSON format.

```
{"data":[{"structure":{"@module":"pymatgen.core.structure","@class":"Structure","charge":0,"lattice":{"matrix":[[2.18050236,0.0,1.25891346],[0.72683412,2.05579703,1.25891346],[-0.0,0.0,2.51782692]],"pbc":[true,true,true],"a":2.5178271667719256,"b":2.5178269134954783,"c":2.51782692,"alpha":59.99999991454224,"beta":60.00000324214051,"gamma":59.9999988338285,"volume":11.286587893379405},"properties":{},"sites":[{"species":[{"element":"C","occu":1}],"abc":[0.875,0.875,0.875],"xyz":[2.54391942,1.7988224012499998,4.40619711],"properties":{"magmom":0.0},"label":"C"},{"species":[{"element":"C","occu":1}],"abc":[0.125,0.125,0.125],"xyz":[0.36341706,0.25697462875,0.62945673],"properties":{"magmom":0.0},"label":"C"}]}}],"meta":{"api_version":"0.63.2","time_stamp":"2024-02-27T04:59:45.684403","total_doc":1,"max_limit":1000,"default_fields":["material_id"]}}
```

**Is there a library out there that can read Pymatgen format? is this really an existing format in disguise?**

[Online tutorial](https://matgenb.materialsvirtuallab.org/2013/01/01/Molecule.html) basically say, "use the pymatgen library (from Python), read the string from the MP REST API, covert to CIF/POSCAR, etc".

I have created an issue on the [OpenBabel repo](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/issues/2675), but haven't received a response yet.

Comment: +1, Are you looking for a parser to extract the related structure from JSON format?

Comment: @JaafarMehrez, yes. Ideally, this should be in OB.